# Add css class to a specific (starter) date in PHP calendar

Tags: php

I want to highlight every 1 week out of 2 starting from a specific date in a php calendar.
So if date is equal to xx, then add class to its container (li). From there, i'll be able to style it.

How can I target a specific date and add a css class to it?

I'm using this code I grabbed from: https://www.startutorial.com/articles/view/how-to-build-a-web-calendar-in-php

```
<?php

class Calendar {

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
    public function __construct(){
        $this->naviHref = htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
    }

    /********************* PROPERTY ********************/
    private $dayLabels = array("Lun","Mar","Mer","Jeu","Ven","Sam","Dim");

    private $currentYear=0;

    private $currentMonth=0;

    private $currentDay=0;

    private $currentDate=null;

    private $daysInMonth=0;

    private $naviHref= null;

    /********************* PUBLIC **********************/

    /**
    * print out the calendar
    */
    public function show() {
        $year  = null;

        $month = null;

        if(null==$year&&isset($_GET['year'])){

            $year = $_GET['year'];

        }else if(null==$year){

            $year = date("Y",time());

        }

        if(null==$month&&isset($_GET['month'])){

            $month = $_GET['month'];

        }else if(null==$month){

            $month = date("m",time());

        }

        $this->currentYear=$year;

        $this->currentMonth=$month;

        $this->daysInMonth=$this->_daysInMonth($month,$year);

        $content='<div id="calendar">'.
                        '<div class="box">'.
                        $this->_createNavi().
                        '</div>'.
                        '<div class="box-content">'.
                                '<ul class="label">'.$this->_createLabels().'</ul>';
                                $content.='<div class="clear"></div>';
                                $content.='<ul class="dates">';

                                $weeksInMonth = $this->_weeksInMonth($month,$year);
                                // Create weeks in a month
                                for( $i=0; $i<$weeksInMonth; $i++ ){

                                    //Create days in a week
                                    for($j=1;$j<=7;$j++){
                                        $content.=$this->_showDay($i*7+$j);
                                    }
                                }

                                $content.='</ul>';

                                $content.='<div class="clear"></div>';

                        $content.='</div>';

        $content.='</div>';
        return $content;
    }

    /********************* PRIVATE **********************/
    /**
    * create the li element for ul
    */
    private function _showDay($cellNumber){

        if($this->currentDay==0){

            $firstDayOfTheWeek = date('N',strtotime($this->currentYear.'-'.$this->currentMonth.'-01'));

            if(intval($cellNumber) == intval($firstDayOfTheWeek)){

                $this->currentDay=1;

            }
        }

        if( ($this->currentDay!=0)&&($this->currentDay<=$this->daysInMonth) ){

            $this->currentDate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($this->currentYear.'-'.$this->currentMonth.'-'.($this->currentDay)));

            $cellContent = $this->currentDay;

            $this->currentDay++;

        }else{

            $this->currentDate =null;

            $cellContent=null;
        }


        return '<li id="li-'.$this->currentDate.'" class="'.($cellNumber%7==1?' start ':($cellNumber%7==0?' end ':' ')).
                ($cellContent==null?'mask':'').'">'.$cellContent.'</li>';
    }

    /**
    * create navigation
    */
    private function _createNavi(){

        $nextMonth = $this->currentMonth==12?1:intval($this->currentMonth)+1;

        $nextYear = $this->currentMonth==12?intval($this->currentYear)+1:$this->currentYear;

        $preMonth = $this->currentMonth==1?12:intval($this->currentMonth)-1;

        $preYear = $this->currentMonth==1?intval($this->currentYear)-1:$this->currentYear;

        return
            '<div class="header">'.
                '<a class="prev" href="'.$this->naviHref.'?month='.sprintf('%02d',$preMonth).'&year='.$preYear.'">Prev</a>'.
                    '<span class="title">'.date('Y M',strtotime($this->currentYear.'-'.$this->currentMonth.'-1')).'</span>'.
                '<a class="next" href="'.$this->naviHref.'?month='.sprintf("%02d", $nextMonth).'&year='.$nextYear.'">Next</a>'.
            '</div>';
    }

    /**
    * create calendar week labels
    */
    private function _createLabels(){

        $content='';

        foreach($this->dayLabels as $index=>$label){

            $content.='<li class="'.($label==6?'end title':'start title').' title">'.$label.'</li>';

        }

        return $content;
    }



    /**
    * calculate number of weeks in a particular month
    */
    private function _weeksInMonth($month=null,$year=null){

        if( null==($year) ) {
            $year =  date("Y",time());
        }

        if(null==($month)) {
            $month = date("m",time());
        }

        // find number of days in this month
        $daysInMonths = $this->_daysInMonth($month,$year);

        $numOfweeks = ($daysInMonths%7==0?0:1) + intval($daysInMonths/7);

        $monthEndingDay= date('N',strtotime($year.'-'.$month.'-'.$daysInMonths));

        $monthStartDay = date('N',strtotime($year.'-'.$month.'-01'));

        if($monthEndingDay<$monthStartDay){

            $numOfweeks++;

        }

        return $numOfweeks;
    }

    /**
    * calculate number of days in a particular month
    */
    private function _daysInMonth($month=null,$year=null){

        if(null==($year))
            $year =  date("Y",time());

        if(null==($month))
            $month = date("m",time());

        return date('t',strtotime($year.'-'.$month.'-01'));
    }

}

 ?>
```

Comment: Now that you've stated what you want, can you state what your issue is?

Comment: Good point :) I edited my question. Thanks!

Comment: You still need to add more context, otherwise we'd just be tapping in the dark. Where does this date come from? What are you comparing it to? What is the HTML structure? Show your code and your attempt at solving this. It seems like a single `if` condition would suffice, but you haven't shared any relevant information.

Comment: I added the code I started with.

Comment: So, `_showDay` is the method to focus on, since it's the one that produces the `<li>` element for a day in the calendar. The best option is sending it a parameter (a simple boolean) if it should add your desired class to it or not. When calling it in the loop, you should give it a result of an expression (what it is depends entirely on your own rules).